# Total Quality Management vs Project Management

Tags: methodology

A company has a long history of being [TQM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_quality_management) oriented, now they are looking into injecting project management methodology.

The organization is comfortable using the TQM methods - especially [7-step](http://www.isixsigma.com/methodology/total-quality-management-tqm/brewing-better-beer-tqm/) and [9-step](http://cha-international.com/TQM-Application), how will you approach injecting the PM tools and templates?

Do they have to choose one over the other?

Comment: I don't see Project Management and TQM as two things you can exchange for one another. But then again PM is a very vague term. Can you be a little more specific what you want to change and why?

Answer (score 1):

Projects are a balance of several mutually interacting components. The classic "triangle" is scope, budget and schedule. More current PM theory also includeds Quality (as well as benefits accrued, risk and resources), recognizing that you could for example deliver a project more quickly or at reduced cost if you accept lower levels of end-product quality.

Given this, TQM is one of any number of tools that could be used to help manage the quality of your project products. Where quality assurance tools intersect with PM tools is:

- **Documentation of quality standards for a product.** You can look at these as acceptance criteria. These will help ensure that whoever is making a project product knows what standard to work towards, and also ensure that whoever is confirming that the project product is complete is assessing the deliverable against the same standard.
- **Documentation of ownership of quality measurements.** This itemizes who is responsible and accountable for ensuring that quality standards for deliverable X are achieved, when quality measurements are taken, who verifies that the deliverable meets it's acceptance criteria, etc.